# why scilab is showing inconsistent row, column dimension?

Tags: plot, error-handling, scilab

--> x=-2:0.01:2;

--> clf

--> a=8;

--> y=a^3/(x^2+a^2);

Inconsistent row/column dimensions.

--> plot(x,y)

Undefined variable: y

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a vector, use dot-prefixed operators where applicable:

```
y=a^3./(x.^2+a^2)
```

Comment: Got the result. Thanks a lot :)